# Does this DFA prove closure under Perfect Shuffle?

Tags: finite-automata, closure-properties

I'm self studying Introduction to Theory of computation and I'm a bit confused about a problem definition. I'm trying to understand and verify whether my proof is correct or not.

**Question**: Prove that the regular language is closed under perfect shuffle

The perfect shuffle between two languages $A$ and $B$ is defined as:

$$\{w | w = a_ib_i\cdots a_kb_k\}, \text{ where } a_1\cdots a_k \in A \text{ and }
b_1\cdots b_k \in B \text{ and each } a_i, b_i \in \Sigma\}$$

**Proof**:

If $A = (Q_A, \Sigma_A, \delta_A, l_0, F_A)$ and $B = (Q_B, \Sigma_B, \delta_B, m_0, F_B)$

Let $M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q, F )$ be the machine recognizing the closure of
the language.

where,

1. $$Q = Q_A \cup Q_B$$
2. $$\Sigma = \Sigma_A \cup \Sigma_B$$
3. $$q = l_0$$
4. $$F = F_B$$
5. And

   $$ \delta =
   \begin{cases}
   \delta_1(q_i, r), & \forall r \in A \\
   \delta_2(q_i, r), & \forall r \in B
      \end{cases}$$

   where, $\delta_1(q_i, r) = l_i, \text{ where } l_i \in B$ and
   $\delta_2(q_i, r) = m_{i+1}, \text{ where } m_{i} \in A$.

The confusion about the correctness of proof primarily stems from $F = F_B$ is this something that is true in my DFA of perfect shuffle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work, I am afraid.
Your state space is the union $Q_A\cup Q_B$ of the individual spaces, it should be the direct product $Q_A\times Q_B$ instead. See for example this answer: [Zigzag concatenation of two languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/126566/4287).
The reason is that one should also remember the state of the other automaton when switching between the two.

Comment: But why do we need to remember the state when all we have to do is alternate between the machines, especially since in our case $a_i, b_i \in \Sigma$? Is something like this not possible: https://imgur.com/Gxw1H8z.png

Comment: Yes, that zig-zag is what you are effectively doing, but the next state $l_2$ after $m_1$ is determined by $l_1$ so we should definitely remember that state. The combined "zipped" automaton recalls two states (one from each of the two automata) and also who's turn it is.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why $l_2$ has to depend on $l_1$, when creating the new transition function doesn't the subscript "encode" this information already. Am I wrong to assume subscript encodes such information? Also if I were to write transition function for this wouldn't it be something like what I wrote in the question.

Comment: Like if we can do $\delta(q_i, a) = q_{i+1}$ what is stopping us from $\delta(m_i, b) = l_{i+1}$?

Comment: Upon writing and thinking to myself. I am dumb to think that we can find $l_{i+1}$ without the transition function for language $A$. To say it in more obvious way, $l_{i+1}$ is next to $l_i$ only because of the transition function's existence and we can't get there if we don't have an $l_i$. This will take me a minute more to get it fully. But I think I understand it better now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user5954246 that is the famous "aha, got it" feeling we get when we learn.